# Laravel Shared Hosting: /www/../vendor/autoload.php: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I am trying to host a Laravel application on shared hosting. The default folder is '/www' and can't be changed, there is no public_html folder. However when surfing to the website I get an Error 500 and in the logs I get:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/absolutepath/www/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /absolutepath/www/index.php on line 34PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/absolutepath/www/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.') in /absolutepath/www/index.php on line 34'

Everything works locally and I have followed a guide on how to setup a Laravel project for Shared Hosting. I did the following:

1. Move index.php and .htaccess to the root of the project
2. Changed `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` in index.php
3. Changed `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';` in index.php
4. Changed `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';` to `require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';` in server.php

My file structure looks as follows:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAybe.png)

I have already tried:

- composer update & composer dump-autoload
- composer install
- php artisan key:generate

Also:

- php artisan route:cache
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan config:cache

Comment: First of all, don't put laravel in the (public) www folder. thats a security risk. The laravel public folder needs to be the root folder of your domain. If you really can't change the pointer for your domain (I doubt that that is the case), you can replace the www folder with a symlink to the public folder

Comment: as you have host your site in shared hosting you don't have access of command line so you need to upload vendor folder using FileZilla or WinSCP. First check vendor folder is there in your root directory or not?

Comment: @sandipbharadva in the question it is clear the OP has access to "command line". Manually uploading the vendor folder is a bad idea...

Comment: @GertB. the "server folder" is set to "/www" and I can't change that, I have even contacted customer support and they are not willing to change this ("not possible"...). I'll be trying your alternative solution asap but it's taking a while to move everything around.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried to rename "/public" to "/www" (and refactoring all /public to /www). Again, project worked locally, but didn't work on the server.

Comment: @Tdemunck That's indeed customer support that is not willing to help you out. It's quite easy to change. The symlink will solve that problem, but keep in mind that you need the original code to make it work. Too bad that some hosting partners reply with "not possible" on such an easy request.

Comment: in your file structure i have seen .htaccess file in root directory so you need to rename server.php to index.php

Comment: @sandipbharadva server.php is used for the artisan serve functionality... why would you change that? The Laravel core should never be in a public folder.

Comment: @GertB. thank you so much for all the help, this indeed solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help.